# Display hidden div if no more data found

Tags: php, html, ajax

So currently I'm searching for 10 new posts and the Ajax searches in the same page from the page and I use `$_GET['limits']` in my PHP query to scan the server for all requested data.

So what I'd like to do is if there is no new data to show the 'No More Posts' Div. I tried using t.length===0 with no luck, now I don't know if its because t isn't an array or whether I put it in the wrong place in my success.

```
var streams_stream_count=10;    
function streams_stream_load(targetID){
    $('#loadmorestreamoneajaxloadertarget').show();
    $.ajax({
        method: 'get',
        url : 'stream2.php?limits='+streams_stream_count+'&targetID='+targetID,
        dataType : 'text',
        success: function (t) { 
            $('#streams_stream_container').fadeIn('slow').html(t); 
            $(document).scroll(function(){
                if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
                    streams_stream_count+=10;streams_stream_load(targetID);
                }
            });
        },
        complete: function(){
            $('#loadmorestreamoneajaxloadertarget').hide();
      }
  });
}
```

And my hidden div to show if no new data.

```
<div id='nomoreposts' style='display:none;'>No more Posts</div>
```

**UPDATE**

I use `$sqlLimit=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_GET['limit'])`

```
  $call="SELECT * FROM streamdata ORDER BY streamitem_timestamp DESC LIMIT $sqlLimit";
```

Comment: What does your php return when there is no more data? What does `t` look like in this case? Can you show your php code?

Comment: Hi sean. the response in firebug is my whole php page and that page has over 2000 lines of code So I don't think it would be possible.

Comment: When ajax searches the stream2 page it just constructs all the new data in the page

Comment: So when there is no more results, it is returning your whole page? So how will you know when `streams_stream_count` is larger than your results? How do you use the `limits` value in `stream2.php`?

Comment: See my update in the main question @Sean thank you

Comment: Use [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) to determine if you have any more rows to show. If not, then echo back a specific value. Then in your  `$.ajax::success`, check for that specific value to either show the `No more posts` div, or to show the resulting html.

Comment: Oh yes I have mysqli_num_rows set up too. That's how I determine new data and also use the while. loop. But never thought of doing what you suggested. I'll give it a go. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this :- Write code in backend (PHP function) and return html if no data found "No more Posts", also send one parameter true/false. On the bases of the parameter show html in your fronted.